# Error en datatables al usar el input de búsqueda

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

tengo una tabla creada con el plugin datatables.

se carga correctamente, acá el código de la consulta:

```
    public function tabla(){
        try{
            $sql = DB::table('personas AS p')
                ->select('p.id','p.cedula', 'p.nombres', 'p.apellidos', 'c.nombre AS cargos', 'p.status', 'c.id AS id_cargos')
                ->join('cargos AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'p.id_cargos');
            return Datatables::of($sql)->make(true);
        }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            $array = array(
                'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                'codigo' => $e->getCode(),
                'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
            );
            return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
        }
}
```

si capturo el json que me retorna es

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 12,
  "recordsFiltered": 12,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "cedula": 9335797,
      "nombres": "Johnathan",
      "apellidos": "Waters",
      "cargos": "Receptionist and Information Clerk",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "cedula": 10173957,
      "nombres": "Bessie",
      "apellidos": "Emard",
      "cargos": "Painter",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "cedula": 12017974,
      "nombres": "Eric",
      "apellidos": "Kuhn",
      "cargos": "Receptionist and Information Clerk",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "cedula": 12018717,
      "nombres": "Norbert",
      "apellidos": "Langworth",
      "cargos": "Financial Analyst",
      "status": false,
      "id_cargos": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "cedula": 14034453,
      "nombres": "Dianna",
      "apellidos": "Zemlak",
      "cargos": "Financial Analyst",
      "status": false,
      "id_cargos": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "cedula": 16213327,
      "nombres": "Cora",
      "apellidos": "Funk",
      "cargos": "Technical Program Manager",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "cedula": 19362870,
      "nombres": "Lera",
      "apellidos": "Barton",
      "cargos": "Massage Therapist",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "cedula": 19857587,
      "nombres": "Genesis Andreina",
      "apellidos": "Rodriguez Gomez",
      "cargos": "Architect",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "cedula": 19912901,
      "nombres": "Howell",
      "apellidos": "Balistreri",
      "cargos": "Plumber OR Pipefitter OR Steamfitter",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "cedula": 19974834,
      "nombres": "Pablo Contreras",
      "apellidos": "Contreras Guevara",
      "cargos": "Manager",
      "status": true,
      "id_cargos": 2
    }
  ],
  "queries": [
    {
      "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as \"row_count\" from \"personas\" as \"p\" inner join \"cargos\" as \"c\" on \"c\".\"id\" = \"p\".\"id_cargos\") count_row_table",
      "bindings": [

      ],
      "time": 2.86
    },
    {
      "query": "select \"p\".\"id\", \"p\".\"cedula\", \"p\".\"nombres\", \"p\".\"apellidos\", \"c\".\"nombre\" as \"cargos\", \"p\".\"status\", \"c\".\"id\" as \"id_cargos\" from \"personas\" as \"p\" inner join \"cargos\" as \"c\" on \"c\".\"id\" = \"p\".\"id_cargos\" order by \"cedula\" asc limit 10 offset 0",
      "bindings": [

      ],
      "time": 1.37
    }
  ],
  "input": {
    "draw": "1",
    "columns": [
      {
        "data": "0",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "false",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "cedula",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "true",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "nombres",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "true",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "apellidos",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "true",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "cargos",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "true",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "5",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "true",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "status",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": "true",
        "orderable": "true",
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": "false"
        }
      }
    ],
    "order": [
      {
        "column": "1",
        "dir": "asc"
      }
    ],
    "start": "0",
    "length": "10",
    "search": {
      "value": "",
      "regex": "false"
    },
    "_": "1479441344250"
  }
}
```

pero después que uso el input de buscar me arroja el siguiente error:

> {"ErrorSql":{"mensaje":"SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: no existe la columna \u00abcargos\u00bb\nLINE 1: ...(CAST(\"apellidos\" as TEXT)) LIKE $4 or LOWER(CAST(\"cargos\" a...\n ^\nHINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"p.id_cargos\". (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as \"row_count\" from \"personas\" as \"p\" inner join \"cargos\" as \"c\" on \"c\".\"id\" = \"p\".\"id_cargos\" where (LOWER(CAST(\"p\".\"id\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a% or LOWER(CAST(\"cedula\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a% or LOWER(CAST(\"nombres\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a% or LOWER(CAST(\"apellidos\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a% or LOWER(CAST(\"cargos\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a% or LOWER(CAST(\"p\".\"status\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a% or LOWER(CAST(\"status\" as TEXT)) LIKE %a%)) count_row_table)","codigo":"42703","sql":"select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as \"row_count\" from \"personas\" as \"p\" inner join \"cargos\" as \"c\" on \"c\".\"id\" = \"p\".\"id_cargos\" where (LOWER(CAST(\"p\".\"id\" as TEXT)) LIKE ? or LOWER(CAST(\"cedula\" as TEXT)) LIKE ? or LOWER(CAST(\"nombres\" as TEXT)) LIKE ? or LOWER(CAST(\"apellidos\" as TEXT)) LIKE ? or LOWER(CAST(\"cargos\" as TEXT)) LIKE ? or LOWER(CAST(\"p\".\"status\" as TEXT)) LIKE ? or LOWER(CAST(\"status\" as TEXT)) LIKE ?)) count_row_table","bindings":["%a%","%a%","%a%","%a%","%a%","%a%","%a%"]}}

lo pueden verificar en [jsoneditor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

el error dice "no existe la columna «cargos»", ¿por que? si en la primera consulta no me mostró ningún error, ¿porque lo va a hacer cuando intento usar el buscador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no encontre alguna solucion con respecto al query o alguna otra duda y la unica solucion que encontre fue no obtener los datos por sus nombres, sino por su posicion.

```
            "columns": [
                {data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, searchable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                        return meta.row+1;
                    }
                },
                {data: 1},
                {data: 2},
                {data: 3},
                {data: 4},
                {data: 5},
                {'defaultContent':  '<button type="button" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-info ">'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Editar'+
                                    '</button> '+
                                    '<button type="button" class="eliminar delete-modal btn btn-danger">'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar'+
                                    '</button>'
                },
            ],
```

de esta manera no me lanza errores el sql.

Gracias de igual manera.